# powershell webClient request to couchDB

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm writing a script to automate some tests that execute Http requests.  I've pasted the code and response.  I think the parser is geting hung up on the colon specifying the port.

```
function executeRequest($url){
Write-Host "Entered executeRequest";
$webClient = New-Object net.WebClient;
$webClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin",   "password");
$webClient.Headers.Add("Conten-Type", "application/json");

$webClient.UploadFile("http://127.0.0.1:5984/my_couch_collection", "D:\myFile.json");
}
```

The code errors out:

```
> Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception
> occurred during a WebClient request." At
> D:\staging\scripts\_0001CreateFolderStructure.ps1:8 char:23
> +     $webClient.UploadFile <<<< ("http://127.0.0.1:5984/source_data", "D:\myFile.json");
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I've looked at a dozen tutorials but each one does this differently however all attempts have resulted in some sort of issue referencing the ':' character.

Comment: Can you run that, let it fail, then look at `$error[0].Exception.ToString()`?  This will contain more information about the error.

Comment: Also, $error[0].Exception.StackTrace